# Can I use a tableviewcontroller and the prototype cells to split the screen into three sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to split my ViewController into three equal sections eg. "What", "Why", "Where" and when each view is tapped it goes to a se. I thought about using a UIViewController and having three separate views and then using a tap gesture with each view that takes to an appropriate page.

But then I thought maybe I could use a master-detail tableviewcontroller and an array of three strings to populate each cell.

```
   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

        return 1
    }
```

I don't know which way is more legitimate and with the tableviewcontroller my main issue is cell height. Because there is only one cell in each section ideally i'd like the cell height to take up the full height of the section but not sure if i can set cell height to 100% for example.

Thank.

Comment: Hey please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41310654/3548469 may this help

Comment: you can simply add button in views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want 3 equally sized sections and you're building for `>= iOS9`, the easiest and fastest way would be to just use a vertical `UIStackView`.

Just set it's `alignment` to `fill` and its `distribution` to `fill equally`, drop in 3 `UIButtons`. Give you're stackView's `topAnchor`, `bottomAnchor`, `leadingAnchor` and `trailingAnchor` a constraint of 0 to the `superview`.

Of course you can use a `UITableView`, but it would be quite a lot of work to make sure, that your cells have a third of the screen size each. You would have to ensure that they adapt dynamically based on the screen size (which totally is possible). Also if you use a tableView, for something like this a static one is best. Then you don't have to implement a lot of the delegate methods like `cellForRow` etc.